# Mechanical systems with their configuration space being a Lie group

Tags: classical-mechanics, group-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, hamiltonian, phase-space

In *Marsden, Ratiu - Introduction To Mechanics And Symmetry* there is a certain focus on reducing cotangent bundles of Lie groups. More precisely, if $G$ is a Lie group, then $T^*G$ is naturally a symplectic manifold. Then,

- Lie-Poisson reduction provides a Poisson structure on the Lie coalgebra $\mathfrak{g}^*$ and a reduced Hamiltonian $\mathfrak{g}^* \to \mathbb{R}$. In other words, the dynamics can be analyzed on the reduced space $\mathfrak{g}^*$.
- symplectic reduction allows us to reduce the phase space further and identify the reduced phase space with a coadjoint orbit $\mathcal{O} \subset \mathfrak{g}^*$, where $\mathcal{O}$ is equipped with the KKS symplectic structure.

However, apart from the configuration space $G = SO(3)$ which is the configuration space for the rigid body, all the examples provided by Marsden and Ratiu are infinite-dimensional.  I failed to come up with any other non-trivial finite-dimensional example, i.e. $\mathbb{R}^n \times (SO(3))^k$ doesn't count.

Are there any other naturally occurring mechanical systems, whose configuration space is a Lie group $G$ and that the Hamiltonian $H\colon\,T^*G \to \mathbb{R}$ is $G$-invariant with respect to the natural action of $G$ on $T^*G$?

Comment: A "quasi-rigid" body in relativistic mechanics has an SO(3,1) configuration space, but the additional degree of freedom is a "gauge" one.  The momenta (relativistic spin) then have the commutation relations of the generators of the Lorentz group.

Comment: Fair enough, it's a different group, but on the level of physics it's still conceptually the same.

Comment: I do agree, I think there are very few classical, finite-dimensional systems where this applies. Even more, I think the most important applications will be in quantum field theories (EFTs). I guess that its just that you build the foundations starting from finite-dimensional classical systems.